# BIP 32 Root key for connecting wallets

Tags: transactions, wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, coinbase-transaction, bip

I have a question, a broker Xeroxfx.org asked me to create the BIP 32 RK to connect wallets for a quicker transaction. Is this real, or can he now steal from my wallet?

THX

Phillip

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with the first sentence but you don’t give anyone your private key for any reason ever

Answer (score 3):

If you give him the key, he can remove any money in that wallet and can remove any money placed by you in that wallet anytime in the future

I would distrust anyone making that kind of suggestion and cease all contact with them